# unix user account start and end dates

Tags: linux, unix, user-accounts, user-profiles

Where I used to work the operating system was Solaris, and I found that in addition to the standard utility functions for looking up information about UNIX user IDs and group names such as getpwuid, getgrent, etc., there was also a way to obtain the date on which any given user ID had been inactivated after the associated user had left the company.  I had written an application that was similar to "ls" in that within a console window it would list the contents of the current directory, showing the name, size, creation date, and other fields for each file, and in two columns I had it show the user ID that owned the file and the external full name of the person to whom that user ID was assigned.  In cases where the file owner had left the company, what the regular ls command showed for that row in the file listing was the numeric uid rather than the alphanumeric user ID.  I used the getpwuid function to get the user ID that corresponded to the uid that was displayed, and the gcos value returned by the getpw* function as the user name, and somehow I was also able to find the date on which the user ID had been inactivated due to its user having left the company, which I would display next to that file in my file listing utility.  I now have a similar need to obtain the date on which a given user login ID was last deactivated, and if available, the earliest date on which it was first activated.  However, I am unable to remember how I did it in the Solaris environment and am unable to figure out how to do it in my new environment.  My new environment is the following:

Operating System: RHEL
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.7:GA:server
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks much in advance.